# Getting multiple string input after integer?

Tags: c++, string, c++11, std, getline

I came through this programming question where I need to input multiple strings after inputing a integer.
The string also include spaces.

//Program

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
int t;
cin>>t;
while(t--){
    string s;
    getline(cin,s,'\n');  //also used cin>>s;
    cout<<"$"<<s<<"$"<<'\n';
}
return 0;
}
```

**Input**

```
2
Hello World
Hello StackOverFlow
```

**Expected Output**

```
Hello World
Hello StackOverFlow
```

**Program's Output**

```
$$$Hello World$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that `std::cin >> t;` doesn't consume the `\n` that appears in the input. This is why the first call to `std::getline` reads everything until the next `\n`, which appears immediately (such that `s` is the empty string during the first iteration).

You can fix this in two ways. Without touching the code, adjust the input to

```
2 Hello World
Hello StackOverFlow
```

But I guess that's not the intention. Another way is to tell `std::cin` to ignore everything until the next newline, e.g.

```
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

This eats a possibly huge amount of characters until it encounters the next `\n`. For the above to compile, you need to `#include <limits>`.